# How to do a query with Thinking Sphinx and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have the following models on my Rails app:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :talents, :through => :tags
  has_many :ratings

  define_index do
    indexes [:first_name, :last_name], :as => :name, :type => :string
    has 'AVG(ratings.value)', :as => :ratings, :type => :integer
    has tags(:talent_id), :as => :talent_id
    set_property :delta => true
  end

  def self.ts_search(q, talent)
    User.search q, :with => {:talent_id => talent.id}, :order => 'ratings DESC', :sort_mode => :extended
  end
end

class Talent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :tags
end

class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :talent
end
```

Now I need to retrieve with Thinking Sphinx 2.0.14 all users that have a specific *talent* and sort them by the average value of the ratings of that specific *talent*.

With the function `def ts_search(q, talent)` I retrieve all users with a specific *talent* and sort them by the average value of the ratings of all talents.

How I can modify this function to sort users by the average value of the ratings of that specific *talent*?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible with Sphinx - it has no concept of associated records, hashes/dictionaries or joins, so there's no way to distinguish which rating links to which talent within the scope of each user.

Comment: Hi pat we are working hard to find a solution but without good results. do you have any tips or workaround to make it work? we can modify the database structure if is necessary. Totally blackout :)

Comment: Davide, I'm not sure if it's possible to do that query in Sphinx. You could search on the Talent model instead, which would allow for the calculation of average ratings per talent, but then, each talent can have multiple users, so it's the same kind of problem again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make 'OR' and 'And' query in following ways: 
Assume you want to search with Or condition
query_arr = ["test", "test-xyz"]

Your search query like:
 User.search query_arr.join("( | )")
So your query like "( test )|( test-xyz )" and it will search all user your text match with test or test-xyz

You can make "And" query by just replacing | to &.